# Test spring annotation configuration pass in eclipse but maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit

I have a unit test using spring annotation configuration to autowire bean. It work well in eclipse (Choose Run as > JUnit ...), but fail when I run `mvn test` (Bean is NULL). I don't know what is the different between two. How can I make this run well in maven too? Thanks.

*PasswordTest.java*:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class PasswordTest {

    @Configuration
    static class ContextConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder();
            return passwordEncoder;
        }
    }

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private PasswordEncoder encoder;

    @Test
    public void testPassword() {
        String password = encoder.encode("123"); // Line 43 here
        System.out.println(password);
        assertTrue(password != null && password.length() != 0);
    }

}
```

*pom.xml*

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
...
```

*Maven Output:*

```
Running com.backend.PasswordTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec <<< FAILURE!
com.backend.PasswordTest.testPassword()  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.backend.PasswordTest.testPassword(PasswordTest.java:43)
```

Answer (score 3):

Maven manages JARs and the object lifecycle; that's all.

I'd recommend that you use JUnit 4.x or higher.

You have an @Autowired annotation, which suggests that you want Spring to manage your dependencies, yet you call new to instantiate your PasswordEncoder.  Those two are mutually exclusive.  When you call new, Spring doesn't manage that bean.  If you want Spring to manage them, don't call new.  All objects in an app need be under Spring's control.

I'd also recommend that you write your unit tests without using Spring.  There's no reason for that overhead, especially for a test as simple as this one.